# InputConnection.commitText is replacing the whole text instead of concatenation

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad, inputconnection

I am creating my own custom `keyboard` and I am point the keyboard to the `EditText` using `etInputData.onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo())!!`. In my `layout`, I've used Custom `TextView` and when user clicks on the `TextView`, I use `InputConnection` to `commitText` but instead of concatenating the text and moving the cursor position, it replaces all text as shown in the following images:
[image]

[image]

Following is the `commitText` code on user `click`:

```
override fun onClick(v: View?) {
    if (!::inputConnection.isInitialized) return

    val value = (v as TextView).text.toString()
    inputConnection.commitText(value, 1)
}
```